# Where does one get such detailed diagrams?

Tags: diagram

On the website, justanswer.com, what I assume is well-known car-repair DIYer's site, I've seen lots of these line-drawing diagrams.

Like these,

[image: sample diagram 1] [image: sample diagram 2]

These diagrams seem so useful. Is there a book of them somewhere?
Where do the answering mechanics get them from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about another website, not vehicle mechanics.

Comment: The question isn't about another website, it's asking where are good sources for these diagrams. I think that's on-topic for car maintenance, as a good diagram is very helpful.

Comment: I agree with @Spivonious. Voting to reopen. To the OP's question it's paid for service information from the OEMs.

Comment: I'm going to vote to keep this closed. I have no issues about asking for a diagram to help resolve a specific issue, but for a general site to provide such diagrams does not seem to fit. There needs to be a specific related issue, not a generalized question, otherwise all the OP is asking for is a link to another site (which in and of itself may become stale or go defunct).

Comment: Look for an online parts catalogue for your car

Answer (score 1):

In the manual under engine rebuild or maintenance for your car, it should have diagrams like this